# AnyLogic: how to draw a horizontal cylinder in 3d view

Tags: anylogic

Is there any way to demonstrate a cylinder which is laid down horizontally not vertically in 3d view? something like a roller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Drag and drop a shape of type oval, give it the Z-height you want. Then, create a group with nothing in it but the oval. Then, in the group properties, specify the field `Rotation X, rad:` or `Rotation Y, rad:` as 1.5708 which is equivalent to a 90 degrees rotation. If you want to rotate the cylinder in the XY plane after that, you can simply use the handle when you select the group in the graphical editor and rotate it manually.

Comment: thanks a lot, one more question... how to set new group center point? because it is not fitted on oval center point.

Comment: In the presentation palette you can find an element called group. Drag and drop that element. The location of that element is your group center point. Position it as needed. After that, right-click on the oval and choose add to existing group. Add it to that group you just positioned.

Comment: Alternatively, if the group is already created, if you click on it once, wait a second, then click again, the cylinder will be selected and two arrows will appear. The intersection of these 2 arrows is your group center point. Move the cylinder as it is now selected as an oval and not as a group to have its center match the arrows intersection.

Comment: thanks again... another way I found it now is that after you have made a new group containing an oval which their center points do not coincident, you can select the oval by an extra click and then move it so that its center locates in desired position relative to the group center point.

Comment: interesting simultaneous similar answers...:)