# Rotate or animate a lid opening AnyLogic

Tags: animation, anylogic, agent

I am hoping to be able to open and close a tester lid automatically after an agent has been inserted.
If possible a rotating lid would work great but I have only been able to rotate around the Z axis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AnyLogic: how to draw a horizontal cylinder in 3d view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65950588/anylogic-how-to-draw-a-horizontal-cylinder-in-3d-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the lid's animation into a Group (right-click -> "add to group"). You can then rotate the entire group around the x, y and z axis.